# hidden characters in html source

Tags: python, decoding

In Python 3 (Pycharm) I started with

```
import  selenium
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http.....')
pagesource = browser.page_source
```

Then I have

```
pagesource.replace('</b>', '')
pagesource.replace('<b>', '')

print (pagesource)
```

the script runs fine but in the end the output contains "**Address**"

My assumption there are some hidden characters that prevented tags from being removed. How do I get rid of those characters?

Comment: you stop using replace as "in-place" replacer - it returns a new string. instead you do `pg= pagesource.replace(....)` - might work

Comment: use the power of documentation: [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: new string worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the replaced string.

```
pagesource = pagesource.replace('</b>', '')
pagesource = pagesource.replace('<b>', '')
print (pagesource)
```

or

```
print (pagesource.replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', ''))
```